# Get two types of value in the same column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working with SQL Server Database, and I have one problem like this.

To prevent the users from entering any Null or Zero value into the fields, unfortunately, I have to manage this validation in SQL.

So from the table below, I have ALINUT_Value (last column - always 10 records), , so my question is how to check whether this column that contains JUST NULLs and Zeros (not any other value) in SQL Select?

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ALINUT_NUT_Id, ALINUT_Id, ALINUT_ALI_Id, ALINUT_Value
-----------------------------------------------------

1   200463  18822   0.0000
2   200464  18822   0.0000
3   200466  18822   NULL
4   200465  18822   0.0000
5   200467  18822   NULL
6   200468  18822   NULL
7   200469  18822   NULL
8   200462  18822   0.0000
9   200461  18822   0.0000
10  200470  18822   NULL
```

Another new point for me in SQL,

I have a list of products each product contain 10 lines of ALINUT_value (last column)

Result that I wish to have is all the products that:

- Products with only null for ALINUT_Value column
- Products with only zero for ALINUT_Value column
- Products with both null and zero for ALINUT_Value column
- Ignore other products contain other values rather than just zero and null

This is my table:

```
    PRD_ID, ALI_Id, ALI_ALISRC_Id, ALINUT_NUT_Id, ALINUT_ALI_Id, ALINUT_Value
    263 14177   2   1   14177   30.0000
    263 14177   2   2   14177   40.0000
    263 14177   2   3   14177   60.0000
    263 14177   2   4   14177   50.0000
    263 14177   2   5   14177   47.0000
    263 14177   2   6   14177   80.0000
    263 14177   2   7   14177   90.0000
    263 14177   2   8   14177   20.0000
    263 14177   2   9   14177   10.0000
    263 14177   2   10  14177   NULL 

    304 16880   2   1   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   2   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   3   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   4   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   5   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   6   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   7   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   8   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   9   16880   NULL
    304 16880   2   10  16880   NULL

    305 16880   2   1   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   2   16881   0
    305 16880   2   3   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   4   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   5   16881   0
    305 16880   2   6   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   7   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   8   16881   0
    305 16880   2   9   16881   NULL
    305 16880   2   10  16881   NULL
```

What i have tried so far :

```
SELECT COUNT(Product.PRD_ID) AS COUNTCOLUMNPRD ,PRD_ID,ALISRC_Name,ALINUT_Value
            FROM Product
                INNER JOIN Aliment ON ALI_Id = PRD_ALI_Id
                INNER JOIN AlimentNutrient on ALI_Id = ALINUT_ALI_Id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN AlimentSource ON ALISRC_Id = ALI_ALISRC_Id
            WHERE ALISRC_ALISRCT_Id = 2 and ALINUT_Value = 0 OR ALINUT_Value IS NULL
            GROUP BY PRD_ID,ALISRC_Name,ALINUT_Value
            Having count(Product.PRD_ID) = 10
```

But it doesn't get the products which have both null and values in alinut_value column

Thanks,

Comment: You can use a `WHERE` ALINUT_Value = .NUL. or `WHERE` ALINUT_Value = IS NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (
    not exists 
    (select 1 from MyTable where isnull(ALINUT_Value,0) <> 0)
    )
begin
    print 'ok'
end
```

Comment: calculating on a column before comparing should be avoided, it will usually prevent the use of indexes and slow down performance.

Comment: @ASh : Thanks for your reply, could you please have a look at my updated question above ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer to initial question:

```
Select *
from yourTable
Where ALINUT_Value Is Null or ALINUT_Value = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please have a look at my updated question above ? Thanks

Comment: @Blue Cross in your updated question, would PRD_ID= 263 be the only product returned?

Comment: no the 263 is the only product that i dont want to have in the output, just those with all null / all zeros or both null and zero (2 last products). Thanks

Comment: I have updated my new SQL, it could get those which are null in alinut_value column but not both null and zeros

Comment: Try this WHERE ALISRC_ALISRCT_Id = 2 and (ALINUT_Value = 0 OR ALINUT_Value IS NULL)

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't get the product which have both null and zero value. :(

Comment: What do the results look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp(col1 int identity(200,1),col2 float)

insert into #temp(col2) values(NULL)
insert into #temp(col2) values(5)
insert into #temp(col2) values(0)
insert into #temp(col2) values(11)

select * from #temp where col2 IS NULL or col2 = 0
```

So in your case:

```
select * from ALINUT where ALINUT_VALUE IS NULL OR ALINUT_VALUE = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please have a look at my updated question above ? Thanks